# gradle exclude jar from project dependency

Tags: gradle

This seems like it should be trivially obvious, but I can't find an example. I have a sibling project my project depends on and I mostly want the jars transitively included, but not a couple specific ones. How do you exclude those jars? I've tried this and various flavors of it and can't get it to work. All the examples I can find exclude modules or jars by full artifactory/ivy-like names, but the jar I need to exclude is a jar my own sibling builds so I need to exclude it by name.

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(':sibling')) { exclude('sibling-core.jar') } // does not work :(
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a simple solution.

**In my project jar dependencies I put the sibling project jar at the end of the jar list.**

This way it doesn't interfere with the rest of the jar dependencies.